# What is the purpose of the middle arrow which appears like half moon?

Tags: indian

I recently came across a pic of the bow and arrows of the famous Indian king [Maharana Pratap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharana_Pratap).

I am curious to know what purpose does the half-moon-shaped arrow have, was it used to kill enemies? and also it would be great to learn about others as well, there is another one that appears to be like a ball.(third from middle-left)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google "crescent shaped arrow head".

Comment: Ball may be to kill small animals without damaging skin.

Comment: Welcome; thank you for another question on toxophilia! Question is not trivial, but _is_ a [duplicate](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/62519/1401).  As best I recall, we don't know.  We haven't found any historical sources that explain them.  Birding is a theory (as mentioned above, but we don't have any evidence to support/refute).  For research see  [MarkStretton](https://markstretton.blogspot.com/2016/02/did-crescent-arrow-heat-cut-rope-ship.html) and [Tod's Workshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxHcSSyOTd0).

Comment: https://archive.org/details/dli.ministry.25958/page/102/mode/2up?q=crescent says *"There was one of crescent shape more than four inches across at the barbs. Though they did not penetrate easily, yet when they happen to graze a limb, they cut desperately. When discharged among bodies of troops they were found to do amazing mischief."*